# Javascript is timeout in loop valid

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a visual sorting algorithm. I search through the data and whenever I find a new min I add the selected class. The algorithm works but it shows all the new mins at once and not one at a time. I tried to achieve one by one with setTimeout but this did not work. Is the usage of setTimeout invalid?

Thank you

```js
var gBars = [];
function Bar(index, height){
    this.index = index;
    this.height = height;

    this.getIndex = function(){
        console.log(this.index);
    };

    this.getHeight = function(){
        console.log(this.height);
    };

    this.getStats = function(){
        console.log(this.index + ' ' + this.height);
    }

    this.setHeight = function(h){
        this.height = h;
    }

    this.setIndex = function(i){
        this.index = i;
    }
}

function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode){
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

function setHeight(i, h){
    document.getElementById(i).style.height = h + 'em';
}

function addBar(i, h){
    //base case i = 0
    //first bar
    if(i === 0){
        var currentDiv = document.getElementById("root");
        d = document.createElement('div');
        d.setAttribute("id", 'block'+i);
        d.setAttribute("class", 'block');
        gBars[i] = new Bar(i, h);
        currentDiv.appendChild(d);
        setHeight('block'+i,h);
    }
    else {
        let last = i-1;
        var currentDiv = document.getElementById('block'+last);
        d = document.createElement('div');
        d.setAttribute("id", 'block'+i);
        d.setAttribute("class", 'block');
        gBars[i] = new Bar(i, h);
        insertAfter(d, currentDiv);
        setHeight('block'+i,h);
    }
}

function findMin() {
    let min = gBars[19].height;
    //start at 18 because bars are rotated 180deg
    //go backwards so it appears to go forwards
    var delay = 500;

    for(let i=18; i>=0; i--) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(min > gBars[i].height) {
            min = gBars[i].height;
            var selected = document.getElementById('block'+i);
            selected.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            console.log('new min ' + min);
        }
    }, delay);
    }
    return min;
}

function init(){
    for(let i=0; i<20; i++){
        let ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50 + 1);
        gBars[i] = new Bar(i,ran);
        addBar(i,ran);
    }
    for(let i=0; i<20; i++){
        gBars[i].getStats();
    }

    let min = findMin();
    console.log('min '+ min);
}

init();
```

```css
.selected{
    background-color:blue;
}

.block{
    border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    width:20px;
    background-color:grey;
}

#root{
    display:flex;
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <button>sort</button>
     <div id="root"></div>
 </body>
 <script src="selectionsort.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Your delay is always 500ms in the loop so everything is executed roughly 500ms after

Comment: Try logging `i` in your `setTimeout` function. Is the `i` what you are expecting?

Comment: They are all running at 500ms after each one is created, It is not waiting 500 milliseconds between each iteration of the loop.

Comment: You are basically launching 18 timeouts asynchronously at 500 ms wait as Pierre have said. Instead of creating anonymous function inside loop and passing it in timeout try to create a regular function and call it recursively with timeout delay so it will be sequential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to solve your problem is to create recursive function. It will fire itself after specified delay and once more after delay and once more until you will stop it.

Here, have some code:

```
function findMin() {
    let min = gBars[19].height;
    //start at 18 because bars are rotated 180deg
    //go backwards so it appears to go forwards
    var delay = 500;
    let i = 18
    min = setTimeout(timeout(i, min), delay);
    return min;
}

function timeout(i, min) {
  console.log("Next loop: " + i);
  if(min > gBars[i].height) {
      min = gBars[i].height;
      var selected = document.getElementById('block'+i);
      selected.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      console.log('new min ' + min);
  }
  i--;
  if (i == 0) {
    console.log("End");
    return min;
  } else {
    setTimeout(function(){
      return timeout(i, min);
    },500)
  }
}
```

You can see how it will run only after the previous function has been fired, so after the delay you have set.